# rtabmap depth_registration?

Tags: slam, navigation, rtabmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using rtabmap. rtabmap requires depth/image (sensor_msgs/Image). Does it need a rectified registered depth image or just the raw registered depth image?

I am guessing the registered depth image needs to be in meters.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/260640/rtabmap-depth_registration-?/) by [Archhaskeller](https://answers.ros.org/users/29156/archhaskeller/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7 on 2017-04-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If it is registered to color camera, raw or rect would be the same. The depth should be 1 channel 16bits unsigned for mm or 1 channel 32bits float for meters.

cheers

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2017-04-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1